# auth0 invalid token toward Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api-design, auth0

I'm trying to set up authentication using the Auth0 lock along with a React single page app and a Ruby on Rails API.

```
import React from 'react';
import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';

var Login = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
      this.lock = new Auth0Lock('*************', '****.eu.auth0.com', {
        allowedConnections: ['facebook']
      });
      this.lock.on('authenticated', this._doAuthentication.bind(this));
  },
  showLock: function() {
    this.lock.show();
  },
  _doAuthentication(authResult) {
    console.log('Bearer '+authResult.idToken);
    var request = require("request");

    var options = { method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/authenticate',
      headers: { authorization: 'Bearer '+authResult.idToken } };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log(body);
    });

    console.log(authResult);
    this.setToken(authResult.idToken)
  },

  login() {
    this.lock.show()
  },

  loggedIn() {
    return !!this.getToken()
  },

  setToken(idToken) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', idToken)
  },

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('id_token')
  },

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
    <div className="login-box">
      <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.showLock}>Sign In</button>
    </div>);
  }
});

export default Login;
```

This code comes from the Auth0 documentation. I also configured knock on the Rails API. Still, whenever I click on the "Connect via Facebook" button, I get the following:
- my token is generated (It's a valid token)
- Request is sent, with the correct authorization header
- Rails returns a 401

I made sure Rails receives the header as "Bearer [MY TOKEN]", still getting a 401.

Did I miss something ? Is anything else required ?

Comment: Could you post your rails method in charge of handling this request?

Comment: one but maybe not the only issue here could be CSRF; you are doing a POST without an X-CSRF-Token so protect_from_forgery might hit in here

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally found out: my secret was not 64base encoded, which means the `JWT.base64url_decode` in my knock.rb was not necessary. I removed it, and voila.